# How to push only new commits to the origin when create a pull request?

Tags: git

Am newly using pull requests and it works fine but am skeptical about one thing, when create a new branch for a new feature and then push it to the origin all the commits of the master branch are pushed with that new branch.

When I think I only need to push the new commits of that branch to the origin before open a pull request.

Comment: No you need to push the entire branch. The branch would be useless if it only contained the changed files.

Answer (score 0):

If your git version is less than `2.0`, the default behavior of :

```
git push  # without specifying any remote or branch name
```

is to send to the remote repo all the local branches who have a matching remote branch (including `master`)

You can change this default behavior to `simple` :

```
git config --global push.default simple
```

With this setting, `git push` will only push the active branch. (note : this is the new default behavior in `git >= 2.0`).

In any cases, you can also explicitly write :

```
git push origin my/dev/branch  # push only this specific branch
git push origin HEAD           # push only active branch
```

---

docs :
[git config - push.default](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pushdefault)
[git push - Examples](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_examples)